# Dell XPS 13 9380 640x480 Max resolution in cheese

Tags: 18.04, dell, xps

I just got the Dell XPS 13 9380 windows model and first thing I did was wipe out the HD and install ubuntu 18.04.2.  I noticed in the cheese app the cam and video max resolution is 640x480 and that's the highest resolution I can select in preferences.  How can I get it to use a higher res? I'm assuming it's it driver issue but I'm not really sure how to fix it  This is the output of lsusb -v showing the webcam

```
 ** UNRECOGNIZED:  28 ff 42 49 53 54 00 01 06 01 10 00 00 00 00 00 d1 10 d0 07 d2 11 f4 01 d3 12 f4 01 d4 13 f4 01 d5 14 d0 07 d6 15 f4 01
Interface Association:
  bLength                 8
  bDescriptorType        11
  bFirstInterface         0
  bInterfaceCount         2
  bFunctionClass         14 Video
  bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
  bFunctionProtocol       0 
  iFunction               5 
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              5 
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                13
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
    bcdUVC               1.00
    wTotalLength          103
    dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
    bInCollection           1
    baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID             5
    wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
    bAssocTerminal          0
    bSourceID               4
    iTerminal               0 
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                26
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 3
    guidExtensionCode         {7033f028-1163-2e4a-ba2c-6890eb334016}
    bNumControl             8
    bNrPins                 1
    baSourceID( 0)          2
    bControlSize            1
    bmControls( 0)       0x9f
    iExtension              0 
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                26
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
    bUnitID                 4
    guidExtensionCode         {c385b80f-c268-4745-90f7-8f47579d95fc}
    bNumControl             8
    bNrPins                 1
    baSourceID( 0)          3
    bControlSize            1
    bmControls( 0)       0x0f
    iExtension              0 
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                18
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
    bTerminalID             1
    wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
    bAssocTerminal          0
    iTerminal               0 
    wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
    wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
    wOcularFocalLength            0
    bControlSize                  3
    bmControls           0x0020000e
      Auto-Exposure Mode
      Auto-Exposure Priority
      Exposure Time (Absolute)
  VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                11
    bDescriptorType        36
    bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
  Warning: Descriptor too short
    bUnitID                 2
    bSourceID               1
    wMaxMultiplier          0
    bControlSize            2
    bmControls     0x0000177f
      Brightness
      Contrast
      Hue
      Saturation
      Sharpness
      Gamma
      White Balance Temperature
      Backlight Compensation
      Gain
      Power Line Frequency
      White Balance Temperature, Auto
    iProcessing             0 
    bmVideoStandards     0x 0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
    bInterval               6
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           0
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            15
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
    bNumFormats                         2
    wTotalLength                      389
    bEndPointAddress                  129
    bmInfo                              0
    bTerminalLink                       5
    bStillCaptureMethod                 0
    bTriggerSupport                     0
    bTriggerUsage                       0
    bControlSize                        1
    bmaControls( 0)                    11
    bmaControls( 1)                    11
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            11
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  6 (FORMAT_MJPEG)
    bFormatIndex                        1
    bNumFrameDescriptors                5
    bFlags                              0
      Fixed-size samples: No
    bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
    bAspectRatioX                       0
    bAspectRatioY                       0
    bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
      Interlaced stream or variable: No
      Fields per frame: 1 fields
      Field 1 first: No
      Field pattern: Field 1 only
      bCopyProtect                      0
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
    bFrameIndex                         1
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                           1280
    wHeight                           720
    dwMinBitRate                442368000
    dwMaxBitRate                442368000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843789
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
    bFrameIndex                         2
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            960
    wHeight                           540
    dwMinBitRate                248832000
    dwMaxBitRate                248832000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1037389
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
    bFrameIndex                         3
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            848
    wHeight                           480
    dwMinBitRate                195379200
    dwMaxBitRate                195379200
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      814669
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
    bFrameIndex                         4
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            640
    wHeight                           480
    dwMinBitRate                147456000
    dwMaxBitRate                147456000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614989
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
    bFrameIndex                         5
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            640
    wHeight                           360
    dwMinBitRate                110592000
    dwMaxBitRate                110592000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      461389
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            27
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFormatIndex                        2
    bNumFrameDescriptors                6
    guidFormat                            {59555932-0000-1000-8000-00aa00389b71}
    bBitsPerPixel                      16
    bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
    bAspectRatioX                       0
    bAspectRatioY                       0
    bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
      Interlaced stream or variable: No
      Fields per frame: 2 fields
      Field 1 first: No
      Field pattern: Field 1 only
      bCopyProtect                      0
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         1
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            640
    wHeight                           480
    dwMinBitRate                147456000
    dwMaxBitRate                147456000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         2
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            640
    wHeight                           360
    dwMinBitRate                110592000
    dwMaxBitRate                110592000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         3
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            424
    wHeight                           240
    dwMinBitRate                 48844800
    dwMaxBitRate                 48844800
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      203520
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         4
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            320
    wHeight                           240
    dwMinBitRate                 36864000
    dwMaxBitRate                 36864000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         5
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            320
    wHeight                           180
    dwMinBitRate                 27648000
    dwMaxBitRate                 27648000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      115200
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                            30
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
    bFrameIndex                         6
    bmCapabilities                   0x00
      Still image unsupported
    wWidth                            160
    wHeight                           120
    dwMinBitRate                  9216000
    dwMaxBitRate                  9216000
    dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       38400
    dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
    bFrameIntervalType                  1
    dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
  VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                             6
    bDescriptorType                    36
    bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
    bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
    bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
    bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       1
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0080  1x 128 bytes
    bInterval               1
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       2
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
    bInterval               1
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       3
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0320  1x 800 bytes
    bInterval               1
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       4
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0b20  2x 800 bytes
    bInterval               1
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       5
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x1320  3x 800 bytes
    bInterval               1
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       6
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass        14 Video
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              0 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            5
      Transfer Type            Isochronous
      Synch Type               Asynchronous
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               1
```

Also something odd, when I run discover a lot of my devices are "unknown"

```
unknown unknown 
unknown unknown 
Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
unknown unknown 
unknown unknown 
unknown unknown 
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5385  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: same here... :( .. running 19.04

Comment: And it's not just the XPS.  I have the same problem on my Dell Venue 11 Pro 7140 with both cameras!  (1 x FHD, 1 x 5MP).

Comment: I have the same device (in an XPS15 7590), and I also see max 640x480 in cheese. The specs say 1280x720, and `gst-device-monitor-1.0` lists it as an option in the 'caps'. However, even when using gstreamer directly, I cannot successfully select this resolution: `$ gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device-index=0 ! image/jpeg, framerate=1/1, width=1280, height=720 ! autovideosink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link autovideosrc0 to autovideosink0, autovideosrc0 can't handle caps image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720`

Comment: I did manage to capture 1280x720 images with 'fswebcam', and also under firefox sites like https://webcamtests.com/ report 1280x720 - but the quality remains rather bad despite being spread out over more pixels.

Comment: This just confirms the issue, and that it *seems* to be a general gstreamer issue rather than specific to cheese. Since then I also found some other apps (guvcview and webcamoid) that do 1280x720

Answer (score 1):

This as since [been fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/cheese/-/issues/28) and will do 1280x720 in the next version after 3.38.0 \o/